# Reputation "events" like accept/unaccept can occur too frequently

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New reputation is too verbose: upvote/unupvote, upvote again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again)

With the [new reputation update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) on Stack Overflow, I noticed I suddenly had a `+65 / -45`. Apparently a user was indecisive or over-clicking the accept button. This is reasonable information, but these 6 events happened all in the same minute (maybe even the same 3 seconds).

I tested this out on some poor unsuspecting soul by spamming the accept button:

[image]

I bet it's going to catch him off guard to see a big red `-255` (albeit, next to a green `+255`) that basically means nothing.

If nothing else, this is a cheap way to be disruptive and probably shouldn't be possible. It might be a good idea to have some interval between events, maybe even 5 or 10 seconds, during which accept/unaccept isn't logged. Perhaps even forcing 5 seconds between accept/unaccept actions themselves might be an idea (like comment edits).

Comment: Since I'm sure we're going to see many questions like "Why did I have so much reputation from a single accept?!?" or something along those lines, I happily upvote your question.

Comment: It turns out my test ended up as 58 events, all within one minute. I bet you could really screw up the recipient's `/reputation` page by overflowing the numbers if you were really bored enough. Same thing applies to "downvote/undownvote" events I believe.

Comment: Ahah that would be too cruel. :D

Comment: I'm actually now seeing a lot of very similar feature requests with varying reception. I'll just let this post linger I guess and we'll see how things evolve with the new rep calc/display.

Comment: Oops, just dropped by to delete this and saw "status-completed", thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of an interval, un* actions could just remove the original action from the log if it's been less than 5 seconds.

So you can still accept the wrong answer than quickly unaccept, and since you probably didn't mean to accept it at first (you're unaccepting that fast for any reason other than testing/boredome) you can fully undo. The other user won't ever know their answer was accepted and then unaccepted and wonder why.

Comment: That's what I think, they should just condense the events/rep-change down to what matters. i.e. 4 accepts and 3 unaccepts === 1 accept, 1 event, 15 rep.